# how to find a modules path?

Tags: python, import, module

I'm trying to find a path but it doesn't have the __file__ attribute.

I'm trying to participate in an open project called instapy.
so, I've started reading the code. I want the path of a function. in the code below, I've tried to print the '__file__' attribute but it gives an AttributeError. any other way to do this?

also, this is my first try on an open project. any suggestion would be really appreciated.

```
from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run

print(smart_run.__file__)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Program Files/Python37(64)/Lib/site-packages/Test 2.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(smart_run.__file__)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

Comment: you can try `python -m pip show your_package_name`

Comment: As the error says though, `smart_run` is a function, not a module.

Answer (score 1):

Modules are files, not functions like in your case where you tried to get the corresponding file for the `smart_run` function.

```
import instapy

print(instapy.__file__)
```

Comment: would you mind help me how to read the code written for this project? any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by reading it. You should try to use its api in your small script, like, dunno, getting profile pic of your last subscriber. After you achieved that then you can use breakpoint in your Python IDE and look in its call stack what calls were made and try to figure out why that was needed for the job.